# Can't figure out why onClick is not updating state

Tags: reactjs, onclick, setstate

I know there are similar questions around this issue, but I was unable to use those answers to get my code working..

I want to increment the state of nextPage by 1 every time the button is clicked.

I've tried removing the return in the handleClick Method. I also tried adding a variable to hold the updated num and pass that as the value of state like so

```
handleClick = (num) => {
let x = num++
        return this.setState({
            nextPage: x
        })
    }
```

Nothing I try seems to update state.. This is my current code below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'


class Pages extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            nextPage: 1
        }

    }
    handleClick = (num) => {
        return this.setState({
            nextPage: num++
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='pageNav'>


                <button className="nextButton" onClick={() => this.handleClick}>Next </button>

            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default Pages
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not invoking `handleClick` when you press the button.

```
onClick={() => this.handleClick}
```

is equivalent to

```
onClick={() => {
  return this.handleClick
}}
```

which is not the same as

```
onClick={() => {
  return this.handleClick(/* do you need to pass a number here? */)
}}
```

or

```
onClick={this.handleClick}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. However, I still don't full understand. The top two examples are returning the function while the bottom two are calling it? I tired the 3rd one because that make the most sense and passed in a param of 2, but when clicked, it updates the state to 2, but does not increment it by one as excepted

Comment: You probably want your callback to do something like `this.setState({ nextPage: this.state.nextPage + 1 })` instead

Answer (score 0):

Your click handler is not being called, you would want to change your code like

```
 <button className="nextButton" onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>Next </button>
```

If you want to increment state by one every time you click, you would do so,

```
 handleClick = () => {
    this.setState((state) => { nextPage: state.nextPage + 1 })
 }
```

Here we are passing updater to setState because react batches the state updates, so if you directly access it, it may not be correct

Hope it helps